# loop for applying script to sub-folders and name results accordingly --R

Tags: r, loops, path, subdirectory

I have a script to get corssproduct of test-results.csv file against any exsiting train .csv file in one folder

Edited -- some corrections added

```
mytest <- function(data) {
data01 <- as.matrix(read.csv(file = "test/test-results.csv", sep = ",", header=FALSE))
data02 <- as.matrix(read.csv(file = data, sep = ",", header=FALSE))
test <- list()
test01<- list()
test02<- list()
i<- 1
while (i <= 25){
    test01[[i]] <- c(data01[i,  ])
    test02[[i]] <- c(data02[i,  ])
    test[[i]]<- crossprod(test01[[i]],test02[[i]])
    i <- i+1
}
return(mytest)
}
result <- lapply(list.files(pattern='^tain.*\\.csv', recursive=TRUE, full.names = TRUE),test)
for (i in seq(length(result))) {
 write.csv(do.call(cbind,result),'result.csv', row.names = FALSE) 
}
```

I have few folders with same structure

```
Main|experiment 01|test|test-results.csv, train01.csv, train02.csv, train03.csv
Main|experiment 02|test|test-results.csv, train01.csv, train02.csv
```

I now want to create a script if possible to apply the same script to all of those folders and return the results (e.g. `results-experiment01.csv`) instead of applying them 100 times

sorry if this looks horrible ... new in R

Answer (score 0):

lets say with just plain `dir` or `list.files` call with `recursive = TRUE` you get a file list as character vector (like `dirlist` in example below)

```
> dirlist
[1] "Main/experiment 01/test/a.csv"  "Main/experiment 02/test/b.csv"  "Main/experiment 02/test/d.txt"  "Main/experiment 02/dummy/a.csv"
[5] "temp1.csv"                      "Main/temp2.csv"
```

You can subset this vector using regular expressions as follows

```
> csvfiles <- dirlist[grepl('.*(experiment [0-9]+)/test/.*\\.csv', dirlist)]
> csvfiles
[1] "Main/experiment 01/test/a.csv" "Main/experiment 02/test/b.csv"
```

Then you can get result names using regex again on this.

```
> resultsnames <-  paste('result_', gsub('.*(experiment [0-9]+)/test/.*\\.csv','\\1', csvfiles), sep="")
> resultsnames
[1] "result_experiment 01" "result_experiment 02"
```

Comment: @V-V what are you trying achieve here? Your code is full of errors. what is `test`? what is `files` list created for? what are you trying to do inside loop?